# Half-working Graphviz dot behavior in vim

Tags: vim, graphviz

I'm using Vim 7.4 on Windows and Vim's indentation of Graphviz dot files seems to be half-working.

If I unindent the whole file, highlight all, and use `=`, everything indents fine. But while I'm typing, everything automatically goes to the leftmost column (no indentation).

Here's a sample file just in case I'm typing something wrong:

```
digraph "test" {
    "node1" -> "node2";
    "node2" -> "node3";
}
```

Syntax highlighting of the dot files works fine, as does indentation in other files (Java, XML, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you are not setting `smartindent` or `cindent`.

Check the output of

```
:set smartindent?
:set cindent?
```

If they return `nosmartindent` and `nocindent` respectively, then adding

```
set smartindent
```

(or `set cindent`) will fix the issue.

From `:h smartindent` :

> Do smart autoindenting when starting a new line.  Works for C-like
>       programs, but can also be used for other languages.

---

1. Then why is the indentation working for other filetypes? This is because special functions designed to tell vim how to indent given lines called `indentexpr` is set for these filetypes (try `:verb set indentexpr?` when editing java files). `:h indentexpr` :

> It is used when a new line is created, for the |=| operator and
>       in Insert mode as specified with the 'indentkeys' option.
>       When this option is not empty, it overrules the 'cindent' and
>       'smartindent' indenting.

2. Why is the indentation works with `=`?  From `:h =`:

> Filter {motion} lines through the external program
>               given with the 'equalprg' option.  When the 'equalprg'
>               option is empty (this is the default), use the
>               internal formatting function |C-indenting| and
>               |'lisp'|.  But when 'indentexpr' is not empty, it will
>               be used instead.